# R: How to store a list within a list?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I am trying to parse data from tables at baseball-reference.com. I want to do so for multiple teams and multiple years. The code below is used to capture each team season link.

```
library(XML)

#Will use for loop to fill in the rest of the link
link_base <- "http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/"
#List of teams
teams <- c("CHC", "STL")
#Year
season <- 2000:2002
#End of link
end_link <- "-schedule-scores.shtml"

links <- list()
for(i in 1:length(teams)){
  links[[i]] <- NaN*seq(length(teams))
  for(j in 1:length(season)){
    links[[i]][j] <- paste0(link_base, teams[i], "/", season[j], end_link)
  }
}
```

This results in:

```
> links
[[1]]
[1] "http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/CHC/2000-schedule-scores.shtml"
[2] "http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/CHC/2001-schedule-scores.shtml"
[3] "http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/CHC/2002-schedule-scores.shtml"

[[2]]
[1] "http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/STL/2000-schedule-scores.shtml"
[2] "http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/STL/2001-schedule-scores.shtml"
[3] "http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/STL/2002-schedule-scores.shtml"
```

Now, for each element in the list, I would like to use the readHTMLTable function so that I can parse information. I have tried doing so:

```
a <- list()
for(i in 1:length(teams)){
  a[[i]] <- NaN*seq(length(teams))
  for(j in 1:length(season)){
    a[[i]][j] <- readHTMLTable(links[[i]][j])
  }
}
```

The readHTMLTable returns a list of length 6:

```
x <- readHTMLTable(links[[1]][1])
> length(x)
[1] 6
```

I would like the 1st element of list a to store to the output from the readHTMLTable function for the "CHC" links. I would like the 2nd element of list a to store the output from the readHTMLTable function for the "STL" links. Thus, the list a would comprise of 2 elements. Both elements would comprise of 3 lists comprising of 6 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works

```
lst <- lapply(links, function(l) lapply(l, function(x) readHTMLTable(x)))

length(lst)
# [1] 2
lengths(lst)
# [1] 3 3
```

The first sublist should have the CHC, the second the STL.